# AWS quicksight login user programmatically without prompt

Tags: amazon-web-services, single-sign-on, saml, amazon-cognito, adfs

Our firm has built a custom admin portal and we want to provide our users a new link called reports which will link to aws quicksight dashboard but we don't want them to log in again in quicksight we cant the app (admin portal) to auto log them in with a specific role to see the dashboard. How can we achieve this?

Answer (score 1):

**Note:** This answer is applicable only if you are using AWS Cognito

In order to generate Quicksight secure dashboard url, follow the below steps:

**Step 1:** Create a new Identity Pool. Go to https://console.aws.amazon.com/cognito/home?region=us-east-1 , click **‘Create new Identity Pool’**

Give an appropriate name.
Go to the **Authentication Providers** section, select **Cognito**.
Give the User Pool ID(your User pool ID) and App Client ID (go to App Clients in userpool and copy id).
Click **‘Create Pool**’. Then click  **‘Allow’** to create roles of the identity pool in IAM.

**Step 2:** Assign Custom policy to the Identity Pool Role

Create a custom policy with the below JSON.

```
{
    "Version": "2012-10-17",
    "Statement": [
        {
            "Action": "quicksight:RegisterUser",
            "Resource": "*",
            "Effect": "Allow"
        },
        {
            "Action": "quicksight:GetDashboardEmbedUrl",
            "Resource": "*",
            "Effect": "Allow"
        },
        {
            "Action": "sts:AssumeRole",
            "Resource": "*",
            "Effect": "Allow"
        }
    ]
}
```

**Note:** if you want to restrict the user to only one dashboard, replace the * with the **dashboard ARN** name in **quicksight:GetDashboardEmbedUrl**,

then goto the roles in IAM.

select the IAM role of the Identity pool and assign custom policy to the role.

**Step 3:** Configuration for generating the temporary IAM(STS) user

Login to your application with the user credentials.
For creating temporary IAM user, we use Cognito credentials.
When user logs in, Cognito generates 3 token IDs - **IDToken, AccessToken, RefreshToken**. These tokens will be sent to your application server.

For creating a temporary IAM user, we use Cognito **Access Token** and credentials will  look like below.

```
AWS.config.region = 'us-east-1';
       AWS.config.credentials = new AWS.CognitoIdentityCredentials({
           IdentityPoolId:"Identity pool ID",
           Logins: {
               'cognito-idp.us-east-1.amazonaws.com/UserPoolID': AccessToken
           }
       });
```

For generating temporary IAM credentials, we call **sts.assume** role method with the below parameters.

```
var params = {
           RoleArn: "Cognito Identity role arn",
           RoleSessionName: "Session name"
       };
sts.assumeRole(params, function (err, data) {
           if (err) console.log( err, err.stack); // an error occurred
           else {
               console.log(data);
})
```

You can add additional parameters like duration (in seconds) for the user.
Now, we will get the **AccessKeyId**, **SecretAccessKey** and **Session Token** of the temporary user.

**Step 4:** Register the User in Quicksight

With the help of same Cognito credentials used in the **Step 3**, we will register the user in quicksight by using the **quicksight.registerUser** method with the below parameters

```
var params = {
                   AwsAccountId: “account id”,
                   Email: 'email',
                   IdentityType: 'IAM' ,
                   Namespace: 'default',
                   UserRole: ADMIN | AUTHOR | READER | RESTRICTED_AUTHOR | RESTRICTED_READER,
                   IamArn: 'Cognito Identity role arn',
                   SessionName: 'session name given in the assume role creation',
               };

quicksight.registerUser(params, function (err, data1) {
                   if (err) console.log("err register user”); // an error occurred
                   else {
                       // console.log("Register User1”);
                   }
               })
```

Now the user will be registered in quicksight.

**Step5:** Update AWS configuration with New credentials.

Below code shows how to configure the AWS.config() with new credentials generated **Step 3**.

```
AWS.config.update({

               accessKeyId: AccessToken,
               secretAccessKey: SecretAccessKey ,
               sessionToken: SessionToken, 
               "region": Region
             });
```

**Step6:** Generate the EmbedURL for Dashboards:

By using the credentials generated in **Step 3**, we will call the **quicksight.getDashboardEmbedUrl** with the below parameters

```
var params = {
AwsAccountId: "account ID",
DashboardId: "dashboard Id",
IdentityType: "IAM",
            ResetDisabled: true,
            SessionLifetimeInMinutes: between 15 to 600 minutes,
            UndoRedoDisabled: True | False
}
quicksight.getDashboardEmbedUrl(params,
                         function (err, data) {
                           if (!err) {
                             console.log( data);
                           } else {
                             console.log(err);
                           }
                         }
                       );
```

Now, we will get the embed url for the dashboard.
Call the **QuickSightEmbedding.embedDashboard** from front end with the help of the above generated url. 
The result will be the dashboard embedded in your application with filter controls.

Comment: How is quicksight user created in step 4 related to temporary IAM user?

My usecase is to return embeddedUrl that shows dashboard with data that is specific to a quicksight user.

Answer (score -1):

AWS support single sign on.
I believe you can use that feature for the users.
please click [here](https://aws.amazon.com/blogs/big-data/amazon-quicksight-now-supports-federated-single-sign-on-using-saml-2-0/) for more information